# How does Django urls are matched?

Tags: python, django

I have a page with a form in it. Its url is

```
url('tasks/searchBook', views.searchBook, name='searchBook'),
```

when I click the submit button of form, it should go to this url

```
url('tasks/searchBookResult/', views.searchBookResult, name='searchBookResult'),
```

Url is changing in address bar but next html file is not rendering.
However if I interchange the place of urls in urls.py file i.e. take the second url on top and first url at bottom then it works fine.

What is happening here?

urls.py file :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url('tasks/searchBook/', views.searchBook, name='searchBook'),
    url('tasks/searchBookResult/', views.searchBookResult, name='searchBookResult'),

]
```

form code in template file :

```
<form action="{% url 'lms:searchBookResult' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="inner centerAlign">
            <input type="text" id="bookId" name="bookId" placeholder="Book ID" class="inputField"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="inner centerAlign">
            <label>OR</label>
        </div>
        <div class="inner centerAlign">
            <input type="text" id="bookTitle" name="bookTitle" placeholder="Book Title" class="inputField"></input>
        </div>
        <div class=" inner centerAlign">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button button-primary" name="searchBook"></input>

        </div>
    </form>
```

views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'lms/loginPage.html')

def searchBook(request):
    return render(request,'lms/tasks/searchBook.html')

def searchBookResult(request):
    return render(request,'lms/tasks/searchBookResult.html')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Url's are matched as regexes in the order they are shown in the urls.py.

Since `searchBook` matches before `searchBookResult`, the first page is returned.

Simply reorder these so `searchBookResult` url is before the other.

```
url('tasks/searchBookResult/', views.searchBookResult, name='searchBookResult'),
url('tasks/searchBook/', views.searchBook, name='searchBook'),
```

Alternatively, you can include a `$` at the end of your url which indicates the end of a line

```
url('tasks/searchBook/$', views.searchBook, name='searchBook'),
```